# Resharper 8.0 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

I've been using Resharper (v8.0.14.856) with VS2012 for some time now, but I've recently installed VS2013. However, Resharper does not appear in the menus for VS2013, or in the options (under Tools->Options).

- I've re-run the installer, and selected VS2013. As far as the
  installer is concerned, it is installed for VS 2013.
- I've tried repairing the install.
- I've tried deleting the
  %AppData%Roaming\JetBrains folder (as suggested elsewhere).
- I've read this:
  http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21204867-ReSharper-is-not-available-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation and I've tried running Visual Studio with /resetskippkgs command line
  key.
- I am an administrator, so I've run the installer as administrator, and I run VS2013 as administrator.
- I've tried running in Compatibility mode for Windows 7
- I've also tried contacting JetBrains, but have yet to receive a reply

Note. I don't have an "\Common7\IDE\Extensions" folder, but I don't have one for my VS2012 install either, and Resharper works just fine there.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 8.1 to work with VS2013.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/11/04/visual-studio-2013-support-resharper-81/

This is also marked with a small "8.1" image on this page:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/

Cheers

Comment: Ahh... the small 8.1... Thanks. Saves me tearing my hair out (which was my next option). I'd actually seen both those links, but the way that first one was written it looked like they'd just added features, not support. Now, where's my free upgrade...?

Comment: You should be eligible. Simply download and install, the license should be retained. I had the same problems when I moved from VS12 to VS13 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I Googled around and found a blog post explaining how to add a previously installed Resharper to various newly installed versions of Visual Studio on your machine via the Windows Control Panel.

The article outlines these steps...

1. Go to 'Control Panel' and select 'Programs and Features'.
2. Select 'JetBrains ReSharper' and click on 'Change'.
3. The ReSharper Setup main dialog will appear, here click on 'Change'.
4. The ReSharper Setup integration options dialog will appear, check the Visual Studio version that that you wish to enable ReSharper in. Click 'Install'.

Here is the original blog post...

http://fitgeekgirl.com/2014/02/25/enabling-already-installed-resharper-for-newly-installed-visual-studio/